# java - Dividing string after x words

Tags: java, split

I have a String which is always changing and is like a random statement. What I want to do is after 10 words I want to split the string so it's 2 lines when I print it.

So for example:

```
String s = "A random statement about anything can go here and it won't change anything."
```

Then I want that to be split every tenth word, so after 'it' it gets split and then it will look something like this:

```
String[] arrayOfString;
System.out.println(arrayOfString[0]); -> which prints "A random statement about anything can go here and it"
System.out.println(arrayOfString[1]); -> which prints "won't change anything."
```

Any help towards this would be great, thanks!

Comment: @RayLloy Substring wil help in index but for him its words not characters

Comment: Oh yeah ! you are right  sorry i delete my comment !! but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) can be use

Comment: A quick solution would be to use a tokenizer or split on whitespace to get the individual words, then construct them back into ten-word-strings.
But as @ShreyasSarvothama asks, what have you tried and what went wrong with it?

Comment: Well so far I've tried to replace the spaces with a different character and then count how many times that character is shown, then after that it would put that into a string, but then I ran into the problem of, how do I save all the characters before that into 1 string, with spaces, and all the rest into another :/ it's just given me a massive brain ache thinking about it haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code: The code assumes you split to a maximum of 10 times, you can it to Integer.MAX_VALUE as well

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "A random statement about anything can go here and it won't change anything.";
    int spaceCount =0;
    int lastIndex=0;
    String[] stringSplitted = new String[10];//assuming the sentence has 100 words or less, you can change the value to Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of 10


    int stringLength=0;//this will give the character count in the string to be split

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)==' '){   //check whether the character is a space, if yes then count the words           
            spaceCount++;// increment the count as you have encountered a word              
        }
        if(spaceCount==10){     //after encountering 10 words split the sentence from lastIndex to the 10th word. For the first time lastIndex would be zero that is starting position of the string        
            stringSplitted[stringLength++] = s.substring(lastIndex, i);
            lastIndex=i;// to get the next part of the sentence, set the last index to 10th word
            spaceCount=0;//set the number of spaces to zero to starting counting the next 10 words
            System.out.println(stringSplitted[0]);
        }
    }
    stringSplitted[stringLength++] = s.substring(lastIndex,s.length()-1);//If the sentence has 14 words, only 10 words would be copied to stringSplitted array, this would copy rest of the 4 words into the string splitted array

    for(int i=0;i<stringSplitted.length;i++){
        if(stringSplitted[i]!=null)
            System.out.println(stringSplitted[i]);//Print the splitted strings here
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I will test this now thanks so much :)

Comment: Why not use `String.split(" ")` to find word count? I don't see any reason for finding spaces the way you're doing it.

Comment: @px06 who said we cant do it? its just another way. But when we use split(" ") method, we again have to find the 10th word index and repeat all over again.. better you code it, so that you will see the difference....

Here I am just scanning character by character so that we have index count, if we do split method, we again have to trace back character index... right?

Comment: Why do we need to trace back character index? This question isn't about characters, in any case you can see my answer where I'm using `String#split`

Comment: @px06 yes your solution will work too, i never denied we cannot work with split method. Dont you think the complexity is a little more in your case? I mean the run time

Comment: Yes it definitely is high, probably higher than yours because I'm using nested loops. However the main reason to post it was to show another solution with `split`.

Comment: @px06 cool.. then I would suggest add some comments or give some description so that they can understand better and in a shorter time.. At starting when i was learning to code I used to find it very difficult to understand code with no comments or explanation

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you another solution. I think this is easier to read, because it works without index-operations on arrays:

```
package stack;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 /**
 * This class can Split texts.
 */
 public class Splitter
 {

 public static final String WHITESPACE = " ";
 public static final String LINEBREAK = System.getProperty("line.separator");

 /**
  * Insert line-breaks into the text so that each line has maximum number of words.
  *
  * @param text         the text to insert line-breaks into
  * @param wordsPerLine maximum number of words per line
  * @return a new text with linebreaks
  */
  String splitString(String text, int wordsPerLine)
  {
    final StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();

    final StringTokenizer wordTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text);
    long wordCount = 1;
    while (wordTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        newText.append(wordTokenizer.nextToken());
        if (wordTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            if (wordCount++ % wordsPerLine == 0)
            {
                newText.append(LINEBREAK);
            }
            else
            {
                newText.append(WHITESPACE);
            }
        }
    }
    return newText.toString();
   }
}
```

And the corrosponding JUnit-Test, which use AssertJ-Library:

```
package stack;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SplitterTest
{
 private final Splitter sut = new Splitter();

@Test
public void splitDemoTextAfter10Words() throws Exception
{
    final String actual = sut.splitString(
        "A random statement about anything can go here and it won't change anything.", 10);

    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo("A random statement about anything can go here and it\r\n"
                                 + "won't change anything.");
}

@Test
public void splitNumerText() throws Exception
{

    final String actual = sut.splitString("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12", 4);

    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo("1 2 3 4\r\n5 6 7 8\r\n9 10 11 12");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(
            Arrays.toString(
            splitSentence(
            "Random sentences can also spur creativity in other types of projects being done. If you are trying to come up with a new concept, a new idea or a new product, a random sentence may help you find unique qualities you may not have considered. Trying to incorporate the sentence into your project can help you look at it in different and unexpected ways than you would normally on your own."
            ,10)));
    }

    public static String[] splitSentence(String sentence, int amount){
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        int arraySize = (int)Math.ceil((double)words.length/amount);
        String[] output = new String[arraySize];
        int index=0;
        int fullLines = (int)Math.floor((double)words.length/amount);

        for(int i=0; i<fullLines; i++){
            String appender = "";
            for(int j=0; j<amount; j++){
                appender += words[index]+" ";
                index++;
            }
            output[i] = appender;
        }
        String appender = "";
        for(int i=index; i<words.length; i++){
            appender += words[index]+" ";
            index++;
        }
        output[fullLines] = appender;
        return output;
    }

}
```